# How to choose the values of 'n_estimators' and 'seed' in XGBRegressor?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-science, random-forest, xgboost

I only know linear regression and nothing else. Any shorthand explanations or tricks would do.

Comment: The seed is for making the prices deterministic, any value should do. As for any other parameter, ead about hyper parameter tuning.

Comment: Please follow these steps:
1. Read the following documentation: [SO Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
2. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65964265/edit), and rephrase the question, providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 3):

`seed` is just a random number to add randomness to the algorithm. Just put your lucky number there.

`n_estimators` is a hyperparameter that determines how many trees/estimators are built within the ensemble model. The more you use, the more accurate it's because of the nature of the Gradient Boosting algorithm. The downside is that the larger `n_estimators` size it's the longer it takes to train and also can, potentially, overfit to your train data, but again, considering the nature of the algorithm it may not.

Another thing regarding `n_estimators` to consider is that you can achieve a good score with not much estimators (i.e. 300 or 500) and after that point, larger estimators (i.e. 2000) doesn't add nothing more than a potential overfit.